# Something blocks Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Left/Right

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, 20.10

I have been using Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Left/Right in my code editor for a while and i think about a week or 2 ago, after some updates, these keybinds are now no longer reaching my code editor or any other program for that matter, it doesn't do anything either though, it's not switching workspace or anything, i'm not sure why as when looking at the output of `gsettings list-recursively  org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings | sort | more` there is no shortcut using this key combo, so what i am wondering is if there are any other places i could look for keybinds used by gnome or anything else that could block them from reaching any program.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.10

My current keybinds based on the output of the command i listed before:

```
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings activate-window-menu ['<Alt>space']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings always-on-top @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings begin-move ['<Alt>F7']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings begin-resize ['<Alt>F8']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings close ['<Alt>F4']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-group ['<Alt>F6']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-group-backward ['<Shift><Alt>F6']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-panels-backward ['<Shift><Control><Alt>Es
cape']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-panels ['<Control><Alt>Escape']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-windows ['<Alt>Escape']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-windows-backward ['<Shift><Alt>Escape']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings lower @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings maximize-horizontally @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings maximize ['<Super>Up']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings maximize-vertically @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings minimize ['<Super>h']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-center @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-ne @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-nw @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-se @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-sw @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-monitor-down ['<Primary><Super>Down']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-monitor-left ['<Primary><Super>Left']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-monitor-right ['<Primary><Super>Right']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-monitor-up ['<Primary><Super>Up']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-e @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-n @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-s @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-w @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-10 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-11 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-12 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-1 ['<Super><Shift>Home']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-2 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-3 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-4 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-5 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-6 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-7 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-8 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-9 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-down @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-last @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-left ['<Control><Alt><Super>Left']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-right ['<Control><Alt><Super>Right']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-up @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-run-dialog ['<Super>R']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings raise @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings raise-or-lower @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings set-spew-mark @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings show-desktop ['']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications-backward @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group-backward ['<Shift><Super>Above_Tab', '<Shift><Alt>Above_Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group ['<Super>Above_Tab', '<Alt>Above_Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source-backward ['<Shift><Super>space', '<Shift>XF86Keyboard']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source ['<Super>space', 'XF86Keyboard']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-panels @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-panels-backward @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-10 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-11 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-12 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-1 ['<Super><Alt>1']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-2 ['<Super><Alt>2']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-3 ['<Super><Alt>3']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-4 ['<Super><Alt>4']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-5 ['<Super><Alt>5']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-6 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-7 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-8 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-9 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-last @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left ['<Control><Alt>Left']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right ['<Control><Alt>Right']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows ['<Alt>Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows-backward ['<Shift><Alt>Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-above @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-fullscreen @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-maximized ['<Alt>F10']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-on-all-workspaces @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-shaded @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings unmaximize ['<Super>Down', '<Alt>F5']
```

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 has reached its end of life. It is off topic here. Please upgrade to a current version of Ubuntu.

Comment: As this post is 1.5 year old i'm currently on 22.04, also the issue resolved it self about 2 weeks after i posted this for no apparent reason and hasn't come back, i left it unanswered as i don't have an explanation for why it's fixed

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu binds this key combination to Switch Workspace. Starting from Ubuntu 18.04, you need to use the command line to change the shortcut, because the Ubuntu Keyboard Settings GUI might not show this option. To remove the offending shortcuts completely, allowing IntelliJ to use them, these commands worked for me:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right "[]
```

If you ever want to restore the shortcuts, use:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right
```

In addition, your IntelliJ installation might be set to the the default for GNOME keymap instead of the one you're used to. This maps the *Navigate* - *Forward* and *Navigate* - *Backward* shortcuts to `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Windows Key` + `Left/Right`. Under `File > Settings > Keymap`, you can either modify the key combination for just those shortcuts, or switch to the default keymap entirely.